# Cannot deploy application to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Trying to deploy apllication to heroku, but after running i recieve:

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

heroku run rails console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    
    46: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    45: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
    44: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    43: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    42: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    41: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    40: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in `perform'
    39: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    38: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    37: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:360:in `require_environment!'
    36: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    35: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    34: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    33: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    32: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    31: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    30: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    29: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    27: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    26: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
    25: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    24: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    23: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    21: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    20: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    19: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    18: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    17: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    15: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    14: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    13: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    12: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:129:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    11: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
    10: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
     9: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
     8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
     7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
     6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in `block in execute_hook'
     5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/carrierwave-2.1.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:77:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
     4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/carrierwave-2.1.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:68:in `eager_load'
     3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fog-core-2.2.3/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:30:in `new'
     2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fog-core-2.2.3/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
     1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fog-core-2.2.3/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fog-core-2.2.3/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
```

below is - heroku logs --tail

```
2021-02-01T01:36:43.200387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-01T01:36:43.239093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-01T01:36:47.051622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-wave-48602.herokuapp.com request_id=22ced640-2037-4a8d-b3f1-95cafde10e71 fwd="139.28.219.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-01T01:36:48.729860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-wave-48602.herokuapp.com request_id=22b0a14b-6640-4988-bde8-96d7416feed6 fwd="139.28.219.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Help please, what I'm doing wrong? In development application works

Comment: `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)`...need to set these as environment variables in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you used `carrierwave`, so you should have a config file similar to this:

```rb
# config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:      ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key:  ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region:                'us-west-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
end
```

And `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)` suggests you didn't config the keys on Heroku.

So you could config the keys on command:

```rb
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_key
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_key
```